# How to check that document.location.assign was called with specific url

Tags: javascript, jestjs, vue-test-utils

I'm testing with jest function what called document.location.assign url with params.

```
sort: function (type){
  document.location.assign(document.location.pathname + '?' + `&order=${type}-asc`);
},
```

How to check in jest that document.location.assign was called with specific url?

```
describe('sort', () => {
global.window = Object.create(window);
const url = "http://localhost:8080/uk/admin/students";
Object.defineProperty(window, 'location', {
    value: {
        href: url
    }
});
test('it calls assign with expected URL',async () => {
    window.location.assign = jest.fn();
    const wrapper = shallowMount(Students)
    await wrapper.find('.sort-by-id').trigger('click')
    await expect(window.location.assign).toHaveBeenCalledWith('/?&order=id-asc')
})
```

})

[image: error in command line]

Comment: You're using `document.location` in the code, but `window.location` in the test. Could that be a problem?

Comment: Yes, it's my fail. Do you know how to after `await expect(window.location.assign).toHaveBeenCalledWith('/?&order=id-asc')` I can add to global object`window.location` search params? It's seems like `Object.defineProperty(window, 'location', {
    value: {
        href: url,
        search: '?param=1'
    }
});`

But it's not working

Comment: The function that I have attached is much more complicated and has a condition on the type. `if (typeSort === 'asc') {
              window.location.assign(document.location.pathname + `?order=${type}-desc`);
            } else {
              window.location.assign(document.location.pathname + `?order=${type}-asc`); 
            }`
After the first call without parameters, I need to add `search` and make a second call

Comment: `window.location.href` is simply a `string` that contains the full url with query parameters and all.